# using where clause before or after select all

Tags: mysql

My question is that if we have to use select * and where clause simultaneously, than which option is more efficient?

```
$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->where('anything');
```

OR

$this->db->where('anything');

$this->db->select('*');

what i concluded from above is if first case than first it will select all and then will use where clause which is less efficient according to my opinion because the effort of selecting all is done?

In second is it possible that where condition will apply?

I am confused?please help

Comment: i think you are using codeigniter and therefor should include the codeigniter tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL queries are atomic, and this two statements should be used in a single query:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE <field> = <value>
```

**SELECT** is used for defining the columns / expression that will be presented.

**WHERE** is a set of Boolean conditions on which rows from the table should be presented.

MySQL will first use the WHERE statement to eliminate rows, and then run SELECT * to present the expressions.